# What is the correct way to transfer ERC20 tokens using delegateCall in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

How to use delegateCall in Solidity to transfer erc20 tokens on behalf of the address calling the function? So basically the Solidity contract is used as a proxy and when the address calling the function is authorised then the request should be forwarded to the token contract. The tokens of the address calling the functions should be transferred. Not on the proxy address.

I tried below already but the transactions keep on failing. Any idea where it is going wrong?

```
function delegateCall1(address token, bytes memory _data) public {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.delegatecall(_data);
    }

function delegateCall2(address token, address _to, uint256 _value) public {
    token.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,uint)", _to, _value));
}`
```

I tried multiple different approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delegatecall` executes code of the target **in the context of the caller**.

So if you execute the `transfer()` function that increases/decreases some storage values (usually a mapping with the balances), it's trying to increase/decrease the storage values in the caller (in this case your contract, not the token contract).

---

If you want to transfer the user's tokens, you can use a combination of `approve()` and `transferFrom()` - which needs to be sent in two separate transactions:

1. The first transaction from the user directly (not through an intermediary contract) to the actual token contract, executing its function `approve(yourContract, amount)` that approves your contract as the spender.
2. And the second transaction to your contract, that executes the token contract's `transferFrom(userAddress, recipientAddress, amount)`.

But it's not technically possible to transfer tokens that belong to a user from within a 3rd party contract unless they previously approved the 3rd party contract to operate the tokens - or unless there's a custom imlpementation within that token contract enabling you (the 3rd party contract) to perform a transfer without approval. Otherwise there would be so many scam contracts just stealing users' tokens without their approval, just because the users can't/don't read code of every possible contract in the chain of calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im trying to think of a way to build in an authentication feature that will see if the transaction is approved/denied via an Oracle. Would something like that make sense to do?

Comment: @Roeldenblanken You can query the approval onchain and don't need an oracle for that. Use this snippet from within your contract: `uint256 allowedAmount = IERC20(tokenAddress).allowance(msg.sender, address(this));` The first argument represents the user address (who approved), the second argument is the address of your contract (approved to whom).

Comment: Ok, the idea is to do more complex analysis of the transaction off-chain. Like for example checking which function is called and input parameters. This information will then be send back to chain and the receiving contract will save this info in a mapping, then the next transaction done by the user will be compared to the approved info and executed if approved.

Because the analysis of the transaction is done off-chain it allows for more processing power. The result will be hashed and then compared to the users next transaction call data to see if that is the transaction that is approved.

Comment: @PetrHejda How does places like coinbase handle these transfer then? Example when people send funds to my USDC wallet. I know coinbase use a forwarder but if I never have to approve anything how does coinbase transfer the token to their central wallet?

Comment: @qasim12321 Coinbase holds private keys to the addresses within their platform. For example they accept the USDC to an address 0x123 which is unique only to you (other users have different addresses assigned). The deposit address is connected to your user ID in their database so that they know how much to credit you. Then they withdraw the USDC from this deposit address to so called hot wallet within their system. And the hot wallet is used for withdrawals out of the platform - again they hold the private key to this address.

Comment: @PetrHejda but then does it not become less profitable for them due to the gas fees they have to pay when they are the one initiating a transfer to their hot wallet?

Comment: @qasim12321 Yes, they usually have a process when to collect funds from the deposit wallets on chains that support only one sender within a transaction (unlike BTC for example where you can combine a transaction from multiple senders)... The wallets might be categorized and assigned different priorities depending on if they currently hold ETH (to cover the gas fees), if they hold one or multiple ERC20 tokens, how often there were previous deposits to the wallet, how scarce on the exchange is the ERC20 token that they want to withdraw, and other params.